# Game flashing to fullscreen when the windowed fuction is called

Tags: java

I am having an issue getting my fullscreen/windowed function to work. Currently my main menu works including the fullscreen/windowed functions. However in my game class it will not work correctly, when going to windowed mode it will just flash into fullscreen mode. I have tried the same code that is in my menu class but it is not working like the main menu does. The problem lies within the game class under WindowButtonHandler. I have ran out of ideas on what could possibly be wrong. Here is all the code for all the classes I have, a total of 4. If you want to reproduce the problem click on "Start game..." press "P" on keyboard and click on "Windowed mode...".

Game(one that causes the issue)

```
/**
 * Write a description of class game here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class game extends JPanel
{
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;
private WindowButtonHandler wbHandler;
private FullButtonHandler fbHandler;

public int I = 0;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");

public static KeyListener listen;

public game()
{
    initGame();
    sound.music("music/background.wav");
}

public void initGame ()
{
    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/char.gif");


    listen = new KeyListener()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton window = new JButton("Windowed mode...");
        JButton full = new JButton("FullScreen...");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit...");
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

            fbHandler = new FullButtonHandler();
            full.addActionListener(fbHandler);

            wbHandler = new WindowButtonHandler();
            window.addActionListener(wbHandler);

            exit.addActionListener(ebHandler);
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {
                int i = 1;
                while(i != 2)
                {

                    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    //exit.setVisible(true);
                    panel.add(full);
                    panel.add(window);
                    panel.add(exit);
                    panel.setOpaque(false);
                    add(panel);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    //sound.stop();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                //sound.music("music/background.wav");
                remove(panel);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
        }
    };
    repaint();
    revalidate();

    background.setIcon(image);
    //menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
    //menu.frame.requestFocus();
    //menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
    //frame.addKeyListener(listen);
    add(background);
    //setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}

public void pause()
{


    System.out.println("test");
}

public class WindowButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        menu.frame.dispose();
        //FullButtonHandler.frame.dispose();
        //menu.frame.setContentPane(menu.background);

        if(I == 0)
        {
            menu.frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            menu.frame.add(new game());


            menu.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
            menu.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
            menu.frame.requestFocus();
            menu.frame.setUndecorated(true);
            menu.frame.setVisible(true);
            ++I;
        }     
        I = 0;
    }
}

public class FullButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        menu.frame.dispose();


        //frame.setContentPane(menu.background);
        if(I == 0)
        {
            menu.frame.add(new game());

            menu.frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
            menu.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
            menu.frame.requestFocus();
            menu.frame.setUndecorated(true);
            menu.frame.setVisible(true);
            ++I;
        }          
        I = 0;
    }
}

public void closeWindow(String Frame)
{
    if(frame.equals("frame1"))
    {
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame1.dispose();
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
    }
    if(frame1.equals("frame"))
    {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame1.dispose();
    }
}

public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Menu

```
/**
 * Write a description of class main here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class menu
{
private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

JButton start, exit, option;

JPanel panel, pane;
public static JFrame frame;
JLabel background;

Random rand = new Random();

int Background = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;
private StartButtonHandler sbHandler;
private OptionButtonHandler obHandler;
private BackButtonHandler bbHandler;
private WindowButtonHandler wbHandler;
private FullButtonHandler fbHandler;
public menu()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
    sound.music("music/theme.wav");

    generate.image(Background);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(generate.getImage()));

    start = new JButton("Start game...");
    option = new JButton("Options...");
    exit = new JButton("Exit game...");

    background = new JLabel();
    background.setIcon(image);
    background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    panel.setOpaque(false);

    sbHandler = new StartButtonHandler();
    obHandler = new OptionButtonHandler();
    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

    start.addActionListener(sbHandler);
    option.addActionListener(obHandler);
    exit.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    panel.add(start);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));

    panel.add(option);
    panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));

    frame.setContentPane(background);
    panel.add(exit);

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.requestFocusInWindow();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public class StartButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.remove(panel);

        //game.game();
        sound.stop();

        frame.add(new game());
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.addKeyListener(game.listen);
    }
}

public class OptionButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        generate.image(Background);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(generate.getImage()));

         background = new JLabel();
         background.setIcon(image);
         background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.remove(panel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton back = new JButton("Back to menu...");
        JButton window = new JButton("Windowed mode...");
        JButton full = new JButton("FullScreen...");

        bbHandler = new BackButtonHandler();
        back.addActionListener(bbHandler);

        wbHandler = new WindowButtonHandler();
        window.addActionListener(wbHandler);

        fbHandler = new FullButtonHandler();
        full.addActionListener(fbHandler);

        pane.setOpaque(false);
        pane.add(window);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));
        pane.add(full);
        pane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 0)));
        pane.add(back);
        //frame.setContentPane(background);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

public class BackButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.remove(pane);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();



        frame.add(panel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

public class WindowButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.dispose();
        frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
        frame.setContentPane(background);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setUndecorated(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

public class FullButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.dispose();
        frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
        frame.setContentPane(background);
        frame.add(pane);

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    menu menu = new menu();
}
}
```

Audio class

```
/**
* Write a description of class music here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;
public class sound
{
static AudioPlayer play = AudioPlayer.player;
static AudioStream stream;
static AudioData data;
static ContinuousAudioDataStream loop;
public static void music(String file)
{

     //loops audio

    try
    {
        stream = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(file)); //loads audio file
        data = stream.getData(); //gets data from the AudioStream
        loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(data); //loops audio
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
    play.start(loop);//plays music
}

public static void stop()
{
    play.stop(loop);
}
}
```

soon to be procedural generation code

```
/**
* Write a description of class random here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class generate
{
public static String images;
public static String image;
public static void image(int number)
{
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
            setImage("images/01.jpg");
            break;
        case 2:
            setImage("images/02.jpg");
            break;
        case 3:
            setImage("images/03.jpg");
            break;
        case 4:
            setImage("images/04.jpg");
            break;
        case 5:
            setImage("images/05.jpg");
            break;
        case 6:
            setImage("images/06.jpg");
            break;
        case 7:
            setImage("images/07.jpg");
            break;
        case 8:
            setImage("images/08.jpg");
            break;
        case 9:
            setImage("images/09.jpg");
            break;
        case 10:
            setImage("images/10.jpg");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
}

public static void setImage(String images)
{
    image = images;
}

public static String getImage()
{
    return image;
}
}
```

EDIT/SOLVED:

```
/**
* Write a description of class game here.
* 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class game extends JPanel
{
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;
private WindowButtonHandler wbHandler;
private FullButtonHandler fbHandler;

public int I = 0;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");

public static KeyListener listen;

public game()
{
    initGame();
    sound.music("music/background.wav");
}

public void initGame ()
{
    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/char.gif");


    listen = new KeyListener()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton window = new JButton("Windowed mode...");
        JButton full = new JButton("FullScreen...");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit...");
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

            fbHandler = new FullButtonHandler();
            full.addActionListener(fbHandler);

            wbHandler = new WindowButtonHandler();
            window.addActionListener(wbHandler);

            exit.addActionListener(ebHandler);
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {
                int i = 1;
                while(i != 2)
                {

                    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    removeAll();
                    panel.remove(full);
                    panel.remove(window);
                    panel.remove(exit);
                    //exit.setVisible(true);

                    panel.setOpaque(false);
                    add(panel);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    //sound.stop();
                    ++i;
                    I = 1;
                    if(I == 1)
                    {
                        panel.add(full);
                        panel.add(window);
                        panel.add(exit);
                        repaint();
                        revalidate();
                        ++I;
                    }
                    I = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                //sound.music("music/background.wav");
                remove(panel);
                if(I == 1)
                {
                    add(new game());
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                    ++I;
                }

                panel.remove(full);
                panel.remove(window);
                panel.remove(exit);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
        }
    };
    repaint();
    revalidate();

    background.setIcon(image);
    //menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
    //menu.frame.requestFocus();
    //menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
    //frame.addKeyListener(listen);
    add(background);
    //setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}

public void pause()
{


    System.out.println("test");
}

public class WindowButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        menu.frame.dispose();
        //FullButtonHandler.frame.dispose();
        //menu.frame.setContentPane(menu.background);

        if(I == 0)
        {

            menu.frame.add(new game());
            menu.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            menu.frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);

            menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
            menu.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
            menu.frame.requestFocus();
            menu.frame.setUndecorated(false);
            menu.frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
            menu.frame.setVisible(true);

            ++I;
        }     

        I = 0;
    }
}

public class FullButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Until the End: The Fallen Souls");
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        menu.frame.dispose();


        //frame.setContentPane(menu.background);
        if(I == 0)
        {
            menu.frame.add(new game());

            menu.frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            menu.frame.addKeyListener(listen);
            menu.frame.requestFocusInWindow();
            menu.frame.setFocusable(true);
            menu.frame.requestFocus();
            menu.frame.setUndecorated(true);
            menu.frame.setVisible(true);
            ++I;
        }          
        I = 0;
    }
}

public void closeWindow(String Frame)
{
    if(frame.equals("frame1"))
    {
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame1.dispose();
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
    }
    if(frame1.equals("frame"))
    {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
        frame1.setVisible(false);
        frame1.dispose();
    }
}

public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: you have alot of static things - that's not gonna help anybody

Comment: I had a problem referencing them @gpasch, it was giving me an error saying I can't access a non-static function within a static so that's why I have all the statics.